# prevent all users including admin to create new post of a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is there any easy way to prevent all users including admins to prevent to create new post of a custom post type.But can edit.

### Below what i tried :

```
function is_edit_page($new_edit = null){
global $pagenow,$typenow;
//make sure we are on the backend
if (!is_admin()) return false;


if($new_edit == "new" && "reviews" == $typenow)
    wp_redirect( admin_url(), 302 );    
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'is_edit_page', 10, 1 );
```

This not works.

### I also tried

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
   'capability_type' => 'post',
   'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow',
    ),
   'map_meta_cap' => true, 
));
```

It also does not works

> It is not also working for other users.like `shop_managers`

Comment: I am fairly certain that what you are asking cannot be done, at least without doing some heavy modifications to the core files. An admin is an admin for a reason, and there is no apparent way to restrict such accounts. What you can do however, is create a custom "Admin" role and restrict that role from creating new posts of a certain post type.

Comment: Hi it also not works for users other than admins

Comment: See [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) about adding capabilities to custom post types.